# Sort JavaScript Array With Both Strings and Numbers into a numbers only array and a string only array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, if-statement

I have an array containing the following data:

`var arr = [30, "Chad", 400, 700, "Brian", "Zander", "allen", 43, 50]`

I want to sort this array into an array containing just the numbers (from lowest to highest) and another array containing just the strings (in alphabetical order--the "a" in Allen is currently lowercase but still should go before the other names).

I assume I would use a for loop combined with an if/else statement but am not sure of the syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function . By default array will be sorted comparing the items as `strings`. So with `numbers` you need to explicitly pass the `sorting function`.

```
.sort((a,b) => a - b);
```

For strings, the default comparing is good.

```js
var arr = [30, "Chad", 400, 700, "Brian", "Zander", "allen", 43, 50]

var numbers = arr.filter(item => typeof item === 'number').sort((a,b) => a - b);
var strings = arr.filter(item => typeof item === 'string').sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(numbers);
console.log(strings);
```

Comment: What if one of the string names is lower case? Like "allen" instead of "Allen." Suggestion?

Comment: @My-name-is-mud by default the `Uppercase` is coming the first

Comment: @My-name-is-mud but you can pass a  function for the `strings` too and use the `localeCompare` function

Comment: Can you give me the syntax for that? Thank you so much.